# Typescript Successfully Creating a Recursive Conditional Type

Tags: typescript

As an exercise I created:

```
type NotRecursive<T, U = never> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends U | T ? never : NotRecursive<T[K], U | T>
}
```

Which works reasonably well [1] but then was browsing the documentation and found this:

> Similar to union and intersection types, conditional types are not permitted to reference themselves recursively. For example the following is an error.
>
> `type ElementType<T> = T extends any[] ? ElementType<T[number]> : T;  // Error`

Why is my `NotRecursive` type valid but the docs example invalid?

[1] would be nice if it failed to create the type rather than allowing it to exist and failing on usage.

Comment: This limitation should be removed in next typescript version https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050

Comment: Great! But why is it an issue now, and how does it differ from what I've done?

Comment: You can try and look at [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3496#issuecomment-128553540) and other comments. I guess the difference is self reference at "top" level (not working example)  and reference in "deeper" level (working mapped type)

Comment: Recursive object types are fine when the compiler knows it won't need recursion to figure out the names of its properties. So `type A = {x: A}` is no problem. Of course, `type A = Record<"x", A>` is conceptually the same thing and it fails, probably because it doesn't spend much effort verifying that `Record<K, V>` only needs `K` to compute the property keys.